# Some subShell problems with python3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, popen

Well, I'm trying to using a python3 script to manage my aliases on my MAC OS X. At first I've put all alias commands in a single file and try to use below code to turn on/off these alias:

```
def enable_alias(self):
    alias_controller = AliasListControl() # just a simple class to handle the single file path and other unimportant things.
    os.popen('cp ~/.bash_aliases ~/.bash_aliases.bak')
    os.popen('cat ' + alias_controller.path + '>> ~/.bash_aliases')
    os.system('source ~/.bash_aliases')

def disable_alias(self):
    os.popen('mv ~/.bash_aliases.bak ~/.bash_aliases')
    os.popen('source ~/.bash_aliases')# maybe I should call some other unalias commands there
```

As you see, there exists an problem. When the script runs to `os.system('source ~/.bash_aliases')`, it will first open A subshell and execute the command, so the source operation will only take effect in the subshell, not the parent shell, then the command finished and the subshell was closed. This means what `os.system('source ~/.bash_aliases')` has done is just in vein.

Comment: This is probably better done with a shell script or function than a python script. You have all the shell commands there (other than the class which seems like it could be replaced), so just put them into a script or wrap them in a [function definition](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_11_02.html).

Comment: Nice idea, well, why not put your answer in the answer field below?

Comment: Where do you get the path from? User input at run time, or hard-wired elsewhere in the program?

Comment: the path leads to a specified configure file in the same folder where the python script resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't address your process problem, but an alternative is to put your commands either into shell scripts or into function definitions that are defined in your `~/.bash_profile`.

For example, as a script:

Create the file `enable_alias.sh`:

```
filename=$1
cp ~/.bash_aliases ~/.bash_aliases.bak
# If you use `cat` here, your aliases file will keep getting longer and longer with repeated definitions...  think you want to use > not >>
cp /path/to/$1.txt ~/.bash_aliases    
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Put this file somewhere in a folder in your `PATH` and make it executable. Then run it as:

```
enable_alias.sh A
```

..where your file of settings, etc is called `A.txt`. The $1 will pass the first value as the file name.

Or alternatively, you could do it as a function, and add that definition to your `.bash_profile`. (Functions can also take `$1` when called.)

```
disable_alias(){
    mv ~/.bash_aliases.bak ~/.bash_aliases
    source ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

As you say, it might be a good idea to put `unalias` commands into your .bash_aliases file as well. It might also be simpler to have copies of aliases as their own files `A.txt` `B.txt` etc and just `cp A.txt ~/.bash_aliases` with the enable command and not use the disable command at all (`disable` is equivalent to enabling file `B.txt`, for example.)

Just some thoughts on another approach that is more 'bash-like'...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OS/X, but I am familiar with bash, so I'll take a shot at this.

First, look into Python's shutil module and/or subprocess module; os.system and os.popen are no longer the best way of doing these things.

Second, don't source a script from a subshell that's going to go away immediately afterward.  Instead, add something like:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

in your ~/.bashrc, so that it'll get used when every new bash is started.

Comment: Thanks, and if I just want to create an alias using a python script and want it to take effect immediately, how to do that?

Comment: If you want preexisting bash's to get the change, you'll need to arrange for them to source your new file.

Comment: Yep, and I still didn't find a way using python script to do the 'source' operation automatically, maybe using a shell script rather than python is a good choice....